# Custom ticks in ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting

I have e.g. the following `data`:

```
data = {{116, 97, 111, 110, 125, 105, 117, 109, 110, 128, 117}, 
        {110, 104, 100, 114, 124, 113, 127, 109, 137, 112, 128}, 
        {129, 115, 114, 132, 87, 131, 118, 127, 117, 125, 99}, 
        {111, 99, 114, 128, 125, 120, 104, 120, 114, 111, 111}}
```

A corresponding `ListDensityPlot` would be:

```
ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   PlotRangePadding -> None, Frame -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

[image]

Now **I would like to change the ticks of the horizontal axis (between 0 and 45) and vertical axis (between 15 und 32).**

I tried the code below whicht unfortunately is wrong. What is the right solution?

```
{xmin, xmax, xstep} = {0, 45, 1};
{ymin, ymax, ystep} = {15, 31, 2};

ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   PlotRangePadding -> None, Frame -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 2,
   FrameTicks -> {{Table[yt, {yt, ymin, ymax, ystep}], None}, 
                  {Table[xt, {xt, xmin, xmax, xstep}], None}}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DataRange` option to rescale you `data`:

```
ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> None, Frame -> True, 
InterpolationOrder -> 2, DataRange -> {{0, 45}, {15, 32}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked `DataRange` ...

Comment: These things often happen to me more than I wish it,  :))...